# Get parent function argument length in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

You're able to access the parent function name with `${FUNCNAME[1]}` ([In BASH, is it possible to get the function name in function body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146623/in-bash-is-it-possible-to-get-the-function-name-in-function-body)). Is there a way to also access the parent function argument length (arity)?

So instead of this:

```
get() {
  [ "$#" != 2 ] && exit 1
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
get() {
  assert_arity 2
}

assert_arity() {
  local arity=${parent_function_arity}
  local value=$1
  [ "${arity}" != "${value}" ] && exit 1
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible:

```
shopt -s extdebug

assert_arity() {
    local arity=${BASH_ARGC[1]}
    local value=$1
    [ "${arity}" != "${value}" ] && echo "nope"
}
```

`BASH_ARGC` is set only in `extdebug` mode. If it is, it is an array of the number of arguments of the whole call stack, with the current frame at index 0.

Comment: So you just add that `shopt -s extdebug` to the top of any bash script to use it?

Comment: Yes, or just before using it (I mean, just before you want to stack the argc).

Comment: any idea how to do this in zsh?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a cleaner code you can pass the actual arguments to the `assert_arity()` function like this:

```
get() {
  assert_arity 2 "$@"
}

assert_arity() {
  local arity=$(( $# - 1 ))
  local value=$1
  [ "${arity}" != "${value}" ] && exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `extdebug` shell option, the arities of the current call stack are stored in the array `BASH_ARGC`.

```
shopt -s extdebug

get () {
  assert_arty 2
}

assert_arity () {
  local arity=${BASH_ARGC[1]}  # 0 is us, 1 is the parent
  local value=$1
  (( arity != value )) && exit 1
}
```